# shell script to fetch top 5 tv shows with the highest average ratings. for same rating choose the one that appears first

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to shell scripting and I want find the top shows according to the rating which should be unique

[image: data format]

Comment: Please [provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) showing what you're attempting to do and where you're stuck. Otherwise, it's pretty much guesswork to know what will actually help you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sort by third column then get first 5 rows.

```
sort -u -nr -k 2,2 myFile | head -5
```

since your file has header, another approach would be

```
tail -nr +2 myFile | sort -u -n -k 2,2 | head -5
```

Comment: i wanted to sort according to the second column the average rating also there should be only one item with each rating i.e  rating 10 should have one value of tconst

Comment: Check my answer please

Comment: this works Thanks! i just used -nr because I want the top rating so that means it has to be in reverse order